# How Do I Remove a String that I Added Using svg.appendChild?

Tags: svg, text

I am trying to build a program that will take a user input in a text box and display it. My problem is that when I enter a new input into the text box hat input overlaps the first text. What I want is that original text to be removed and replaced by the new input. The code I am using is below.

```js
function eccentricityChanged() {
  let svg = document.getElementById('diagram');

  let text = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'text');
  text.setAttribute('x', 585);
  text.setAttribute('y', 275);
  text.setAttribute('fill', 'red');
  svg.appendChild(text);
  svg.selectAll('*').remove();

  let txt = document.getElementById("eccentricity").value;
  parseFloat('text', txt);
  text.innerHTML = txt;
```

Comment: I suppose the x and y and maybe the value for the fill are always the same. Instead of creating a text element every time put an text element in the svg and update only the `textContent` of the text element.

Comment: Okay I think I know what you mean, but how would I go about doing that? I am brand new to JavaScript and only know a small amount.